# How to click A button on the second window of the browser using Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on a project where the agent with python and selenium that do shopping, now when I clicked the google plus button, As shown in diagram, google plus button  works fine but when I tried to  clicked the account (2 number in daigram) in second window with selenium it gives following error ,even I tried it with different selectors:

CODE  :

```
account=driver.find_element_by_class_name('w1I7fb')
account.click()
```

ERROR :

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".w1I7fb"}

[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztBf6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clicking Google Plus button a new window is open.
You have to switch driver to that new window.
So after clicking on the Google Plus button

```
new_window = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(new_window)
```

Now on the new window you should find an element by the following `xpath` `//div[@data-identifier='your_email@gmail.com']` and click it

Comment: Sure, my typo mistake. Sorry. 
If it resolved the problem please accept the answer